# How to filter dstream using transform operation and external RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, pyspark

I used `transform` method in a similar use case as described in **Transform Operation** section of [Transformations on DStreams](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#transformations-on-dstreams):

```
spamInfoRDD = sc.pickleFile(...) # RDD containing spam information
# join data stream with spam information to do data cleaning
cleanedDStream = wordCounts.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.join(spamInfoRDD).filter(...))
```

My code is as follows:

```
sc = SparkContext("local[4]", "myapp")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
ssc.checkpoint('hdfs://localhost:9000/user/spark/checkpoint/')
lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))\
              .map(lambda word: (word, 1))\
              .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
filter_rdd = sc.parallelize([(u'A', 1), (u'B', 1)], 2)
filtered_count = counts.transform(
    lambda rdd: rdd.join(filter_rdd).filter(lambda k, (v1, v2): v1 and not v2)
)
filtered_count.pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

But I get the following error

> It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. 
>   RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

How should I be using my external RDD to filter elements out of a dstream?

Comment: have u got an answer for this one

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the Spark doc example and your code is the use of ssc.checkpoint().

Although the specific code example you provided will work without checkpoint, I guess you actually require it. But the concept of introducing an external RDD into the scope of a checkpointed DStream is potentially invalid: when recovering from a checkpoint, the external RDD may have changed.

I tried to checkpoint the external RDD, but I had no luck with it either.