# Spark checkpointing error when joining static dataset with DStream

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop2

I am trying to use Spark Streaming application in Java. My Spark application reads continuous feed from Hadoop 
directory using ***textFileStream()*** at interval of each 1 Min. 
I need to perform Spark aggregation(group by) operation on incoming DStream. After aggregation, I am joining aggregated `DStream<Key, Value1>` with `RDD<Key, Value2>` 
with `RDD<Key, Value2>` created from static dataset read by ***textFile()*** from hadoop directory.

Problem comes when I enable checkpointing. With empty checkpoint directory, it runs fine. After running 2-3 batches I close it using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and run it again. 
On second run it throws spark exception immediately: **"SPARK-5063"**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063
```

**Following is the Block of Code of spark application:**

```
private void compute(JavaSparkContext sc, JavaStreamingContext ssc) {

   JavaRDD<String> distFile = sc.textFile(MasterFile);      
   JavaDStream<String> file = ssc.textFileStream(inputDir);             

   // Read Master file
   JavaRDD<MasterParseLog> masterLogLines = distFile.flatMap(EXTRACT_MASTER_LOGLINES);
   final JavaPairRDD<String, String> masterRDD = masterLogLines.mapToPair(MASTER_KEY_VALUE_MAPPER);

   // Continuous Streaming file
   JavaDStream<ParseLog> logLines = file.flatMap(EXTRACT_CKT_LOGLINES);

   // calculate the sum of required field and generate group sum RDD
   JavaPairDStream<String, Summary> sumRDD = logLines.mapToPair(CKT_GRP_MAPPER);
   JavaPairDStream<String, Summary> grpSumRDD = sumRDD.reduceByKey(CKT_GRP_SUM);

   //GROUP BY Operation
   JavaPairDStream<String, Summary> grpAvgRDD = grpSumRDD.mapToPair(CKT_GRP_AVG);

   // Join Master RDD with the DStream  //This is the block causing error (without it code is working fine)
   JavaPairDStream<String, Tuple2<String, String>> joinedStream = grpAvgRDD.transformToPair(

       new Function2<JavaPairRDD<String, String>, Time, JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<String, String>>>() {

           private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

           public JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<String, String>> call(
               JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd, Time v2) throws Exception {
               return masterRDD.value().join(rdd);
           }
       }
   );
   joinedStream.print(10);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   JavaStreamingContextFactory contextFactory = new JavaStreamingContextFactory() {
        public JavaStreamingContext create() {

           // Create the context with a 60 second batch size
           SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
           final JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
           JavaStreamingContext ssc1 = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(duration));               

           app.compute(sc, ssc1);

           ssc1.checkpoint(checkPointDir);                       
           return ssc1;
        }
   };

   JavaStreamingContext ssc = JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkPointDir, contextFactory);

   // start the streaming server
   ssc.start();
   logger.info("Streaming server started...");

   // wait for the computations to finish
   ssc.awaitTermination();
   logger.info("Streaming server stopped...");
}
```

I know that block of code which joins static dataset with DStream is causing error, But that is taken from spark-streaming 
page of Apache spark website (sub heading "*stream-dataset join*" under "**Join Operations**"). Please help me to get it working even if 
there is different way of doing it. I need to enable checkpointing in my streaming application.

**Environment Details:**

- Centos6.5 :2 node Cluster
- Java      :1.8
- Spark     :1.4.1
- Hadoop    :2.7.1*

Comment: The example in the latest docs has transform instead of transformtopair, have you tried that?

Comment: I tried already with tranform() but it is not working for me and suggesting to use transformToPair() instead.

Comment: Sounds like a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882256/spark-streaming-filter-using-rdd-external-to-the-dstream