# Joining a DStream and RDD with checkpointing

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, dstream

I've been battling to perform a join between a DStream and a RDD. To set the scene:

- Spark - 2.3.1
- Python - 3.6.3

**RDD**

I'm reading in the RDD from a CSV file, splitting the records and producing a pair RDD.

```
sku_prices = sc.textFile("sku-catalog.csv")\
    .map(lambda line: line.split(","))\
    .map(lambda fields: (fields[0], float(fields[1])))
```

This is the output from `sku_prices.collect()`:

```
[('0003003001', 19.25),
 ('0001017002', 2.25),
 ('0001017003', 3.5),
 ('0003013001', 18.75),
 ('0004017002', 16.5),
 ('0002008001', 2.25),
 ('0004002001', 10.75),
 ('0005020002', 10.5),
 ('0001004002', 3.5),
 ('0002016003', 14.25)]
```

**DStream**

I'm reading the DStream from Kafka.

```
orders = kstream.map(lambda n: n[1]).map(lambda n: json.loads(n))

items = orders.map(lambda order: order['items'])\
              .flatMap(lambda items: [(i['sku'], i['count']) for i in items])\
              .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

When I run `pprint()` on `orders` I get output that looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2018-09-03 06:57:20
-------------------------------------------
('0004002001', 3)
('0002016003', 1)
('0003013001', 1)
```

**Join**

Now I am wanting to join the `items` DStream to the `sku_prices` RDD. I know that I can't make that join directly, but my reading suggests that I can use the `transform()` method on the DStream to do the job. So this is what I have:

```
items.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.join(sku_prices)).pprint()
```

I'm expecting to get a DStream that looks something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2018-09-03 06:57:20
-------------------------------------------
('0004002001', (3, 10.75))
('0002016003', (1, 14.25))
('0003013001', (1, 18.75))
```

The [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transform-operation) suggests that this should work and it does: that result is precisely what I get! :)

**Checkpointing**

However I am also wanting to do a stateful operation, so I need to introduce checkpointing.

```
ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")
```

Simply adding checkpointing results in this error on the `transform()`:

> It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an
>   RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions
>   can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other
>   transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() *
>   x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action
>   cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation.

The answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882256/how-to-filter-dstream-using-transform-operation-and-external-rdd) suggests that checkpointing and external RDDs don't mix. Is there a way around this? Is it possible to join a DStream and a RDD when the StreamingContext has checkpointing enabled?

Thanks,
Andrew.